# Explanation to the details of the proof that $F[x]$ is not finite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I have several questions concerning the proof. I don't think I quite understand the details and motivation of the proof. Here is the proof given by our professor.

The space of polynomials $F[x]$ is not finite-dimensional.

*Proof*. Suppose
$$F[x] = \operatorname{span}\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\}$$

Let us choose a positive integer $N$ such that $N > deg (f_i)$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n$. As $\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\}$
spans $F[x]$ we can find scalars $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n$ such that $x^N = a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 +   \cdots + a_nf_n$. 
Then the polynomial

$$G(x) = x^N - a_1f_1 - a_2f_2 -  \cdots - a_nf_n \equiv 0$$

is a polynomial of degree $N$ which is identically zero. This is a contradiction since $G(x)$ cannot
have more than $N$ roots.

**Questions**

- Why is $G(x)$ **identically** zero and what does it mean for it to be **identically** zero?
- After obtaining that $G(x) = x^N - a_1f_1 - a_2f_2 -  \cdots - a_nf_n \equiv 0$, why must we have more than $N$ roots?
- What is the **motivation** behind choosing $N$ such that $N > deg (f_i)$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n?$
- What are the **implications** if we chose $N$ less than or equal to $f_i$ such that $f_i$ has the greatest degree? How will the proof fail in this case?
- If there are any other important **details** and key **insights** that are worthy to be pointed out please let me know so that I can better my understanding of the argument presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that a polynomial $p(x)$ is *identically zero* is to say that $p(x)=0$ for **all** values of $x$. Here the coefficients $a_1,\dots,a_n$ were chosen so that $$x^N=a_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+\dots+a_nf_n(x)$$ for all values of $x$, and $G(x)$ was defined by $$G(x)=x^N-a_1f_1(x)-a_2f_2(x)-\dots-a_nf_n(x)\;,$$ so for each $x$ we have $$G(x)=x^N-\Big(a_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+\dots+a_nf_n(x)\Big)=0\;.$$ This is exactly what’s meant when we say that $G(x)$ is identically zero and write $G(x)\equiv 0$.

In particular, $G(x)=0$ for **every** value of $x$, so every possible value of $x$ is a root of $G(x)$. Assuming that your field of scalars is infinite, that means that $G(x)$ has infinitely many roots and therefore certainly has more than $N$ roots.

The reason for choosing $N$ to be greater than the degree of any of the $f_i$ is to ensure that the polynomial $$a_1f_1(x)+a_2f_2(x)+\dots+a_nf_n(x)$$ has degree less than $N$, so that when it is subtracted from $x^N$, the resulting polynomial $G(x)$ still has an $x^N$ term, i.e., is still of degree $N$. Otherwise $G(x)$ might actually be the zero polynomial: all of the terms might cancel out. The whole point is to get a polynomial that on the one hand cannot be the zero polynomial, because its leading term is $x^N$, but on the other hand must be the zero polynomial, because it’s the difference of two equal polynomials.

Comment: I'd be a bit careful with saying things like: "To say that a polynomial $p(x)$ is identically zero is to say that $p(x) = 0$ for **all** values of $x$." Because that seems to suggest that a polynomial is a function defined on the ring it's over. Consider $f = X^2 + X$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, but $f$ is certainly not the zero polynomial.

Comment: @kahen: I debated with myself, but finally decided that it was probably a useful paraphrase here, since the context appears to be a first course in linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the proof is this. A basis for the set of all polynomials is
$$1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots,x^n,\ldots$$
If you have a finite basis, there will be some polynomials that you will be missing, in particular polynomials with high degree. For example, if you take the span of
$$x^3+105x^4+x^7, 1+x^8$$
then for sure you'll be missing any polynomial with degree larger than $8$. The rest of the proof is just taking this idea and making it formal. You choose $N$ to be larger than all the degrees since you know that in that case $x^N$ isn't in the span. You prove that by claiming that you can't have the equality
$$x^N = A(x^3+105x^4+x^7) + B(1+x^8)$$
in $F[x]$. If there were an equality, then the difference between the two sides will be the zero polynomial. That's what we mean by *identically zero*. We know that the difference isn't identically zero since, well, it's not the zero polynomial, but rather a degree $N$ polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof in your question is incorrect. Let's assume that $F$ is a field and $x$ an indeterminate. A correct proof might (I believe) go as follows:

Suppose
$$
F[x]=\operatorname{span}\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\}.
$$

Let us choose a positive integer $N$ such that $N > \deg (f_i)$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. As $\{f_1,f_2,\dots,f_n\}$ spans $F[x]$ we can find scalars $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n$ such that 
$$
x^N=a_1f_1+a_2f_2+\cdots+a_nf_n.
$$
This yields the contradiction 
$$
0= x^N - a_1f_1 - a_2f_2 -  \cdots - a_nf_n\neq0.
$$